# jQuery Validate() custom message for array of checkboxes?

Tags: jquery, arrays, jquery-validate

I have the following form that I am trying to customise the validated "required" message for.

Any ideas why my message on `vehicles[]` won't read `My custom message?` as I have specified?

My input:

```
<input id="vehicle-<?php echo $counter;?>" name="vehicles[]" 
       type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $counter; ?>">
```

I'm also pushing into an array (on click) if that makes a difference:

```
$( ".booking-form .button" ).click(function(e) {            

    $('input#'+vehicle_name).val(1);

    $('input#'+vehicle_name).prop('checked', true);

    var vehicles = [];

    $("input[name='vehicles[]']:checked").each(function () {
         vehicles.push(parseInt($(this).val()));
    });

});
```

Handler:

```
booking_form.validate({
    onkeyup: false, 
    submitHandler: booking_form_submit,
    errorElement: 'div',
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if (element.attr("name") == "vehicles[]"){
            error.insertBefore('#no-vehicles-error');
        } else {
            error.insertBefore(element);    
        }

    },
    rules : {
        'vehicles[]': { 
            required: true,
            minlength: 1 
        }
    },
    mesesages : {
        'vehicles[]': {
            required: "My custom message"
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Please show the HTML markup.

Comment: You've misspelled `messages` as `mesesages`.  Otherwise it's working:  http://jsfiddle.net/28L4uLyx/